# How to use retrofit to transfer parameters in parameters?

Tags: android, retrofit2

On the site jsonschema2pojo described the data that I need to transfer.
Using retrofit forward json body. I don’t understand how to **put** the data in the **Delivery class?**

The request body itself is as follows:

```
{
 "phone": "",
"delivery": 
  {
"lat" : "",
"lon" : ""
}
```

Making a request.

```
 NewOrderRequest newOrderRequest = new NewOrderRequest();
    newOrderRequest.setPhone("911");
    newOrderRequest.setDelivery(????);

 NetworkService.getInstance()
                .service()
                .newOrder(newOrderRequest)
```

**Pojo: NewOrderRequest Model**

```
    public class NewOrderRequest {

    @SerializedName("phone")
    @Expose
    private String phone;

    @SerializedName("delivery")
    @Expose
    private Delivery delivery;


    public NewOrderRequest(String phone, Delivery delivery) {
    super();
    this.phone = phone;
    this.delivery = delivery;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

**Pojo : Delivery Model**

```
public class Delivery {

    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
      private String lat;
    @SerializedName("lon")
    @Expose
      private String lon;

    public Delivery(String lat, String lon) {
      super();
       this.lat = lat;
       this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me to solve this issue??

Comment: Please can you explain a bit more about what you want?

Comment: What should I put newOrderRequest.setDelivery (????) here?

Comment: You want `JSON` response to be converted to `POJO` class? or the other way around?

Comment: Try `newOrderRequest.setDelivery(new Delivery("lat", "lon") );`. Replace **lat** and  **lon** with desired value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this

```
String mLat = "lat value"; // value of latitude
String mLong = "long value"; // value of longitude

NewOrderRequest newOrderRequest = new NewOrderRequest();
    newOrderRequest.setPhone("911");
    newOrderRequest.setDelivery(new Delivery(mLat, mLong)); //use this here

NetworkService.getInstance()
                .service()
                .newOrder(newOrderRequest)
```

Hope this will help
Please tell me if you also want to know how to get lat,long